# Is there a better way to check if more than two strings exists on Typo3 fluid?

Tags: if-statement, typo3, fluid

Here is my working code with VHS ViewHelper. I couldn't find a better way using **v:condition.string.contains**.
Another way I used was **v:iterator.explode** to get the string I want and compare it, but maybe there another simpler aproach.

```html
<f:for each="{event.downloadLinks}" as="downloadLink">

  <f:link.typolink parameter="{downloadLink.link}" target="_blank" title="{downloadLink.title}">{downloadLink.title}</f:link.typolink>

  <f:variable name="pathFile" value="{f:link.typolink(parameter: '{downloadLink.link}')}" />

  <v:condition.string.contains haystack="{pathFile}" needle=".jpg">
      <f:then>JPG ICON</f:then>
      <f:else>
        <v:condition.string.contains haystack="{pathFile}" needle=".svg">
          <f:then>SVG ICON</f:then>
          <f:else>
            <v:condition.string.contains haystack="{pathFile}" needle=".pdf">
              <f:then>PDF ICON</f:then>
              <f:else>SOME OTHER ICON</f:else>
            </v:condition.string.contains>
          </f:else>
        </v:condition.string.contains>
      </f:else>
  </v:condition.string.contains>
</f:for>
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure, why you are working with a path of the file instead of a File/FileReference-object... The object would bring the needed property, namely `extension, automatically. ( https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/Frontend.html )

Comment: Hi @JulianHofmann thanks for your answer. I'm not so comfortable with fluid.
I added some more code, I think now it's more understandable why I've chose to check the path. Your solution seems to be the best aproach, but I can't figure out how to access the FileReference object.

Comment: two (and a half) thoughts about your code: 1. what happens if there is a `.jpg` in a folder name or inside the name? 2. why don't you use CSS selectors for icon assignment (`a[href$=".pdf"]`)? 3. what happens if you got images like `flower.JPEG`?

Answer (score 0):

You are already using EXT:vhs, so the [v:resource.file](https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/fluidtypo3/vhs/5.0.1/Resource/File.html)-ViewHelper can help you:

```
<f:variable name="pathFile" value="{f:uri.image(src: 'EXT:example/Resources/Public/IMG_0815.JPG')}" />

<v:resource.file identifier="{pathFile}" onlyProperties="true" as="myFile">
    <f:debug title="myFile">{myFile}</f:debug>
    <p>File extension: {myFile.extension -> f:format.case(mode: 'lower')}</p>
</v:resource.file>
```